# Use a function as input in another function

Tags: r

I am trying to fix the code below. The below code is a simplified version of my real code

```
fa=function(x){
  x+y
}
fb=function(x,func){
  y=rnorm(1)
  func(x)
}
fb(3,fa)
```

Running the code returns the error:

> "Error in func(x) : object 'y' not found".

I can fix it by moving `y=rnorm(1)` to the global environment but I need `y` to be in function since in my real code there is a for loop and y changes in each iteration.

Really appreciate any help to fix this problem

Comment: Variable `y` exists only within the environment of `fb` - `fa` does not have access to this information - this is the problem (You can use `<<-` to assign in the global environment but using `y` as an argument is probably a better idea).

Comment: The natural solution is to pass `y` as an argument to `fa`. Moreover, it's bad practice to make a function depend on what exists somewhere else only, like the `.GlobalEnv`, *even if the function has access* to it.

Comment: The most straightforward thing to do is `fa <- function(x, y) ...` then `func(x, y)` inside of `fb`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match.fun` to pass function as an argument. I'm not sure about what is the best approach for this particular question though.

```
fa = function(x, y){
    x + y
}

set.seed(42)
fb = function(x, func){
    y = rnorm(1)
    match.fun(func)(x, y)
}
fb(3, fa)
#[1] 4.370958
```

Comment: You don't need `match.fun` in this case. It works with passing the function directly, as long as `fa` takes both x and y.